# Postfix Calculator giving me wrong answers

Tags: java, calculator, postfix-notation

I can't seem to figure out why I am getting the wrong answers for my postfix calculator.

My code is:

```
public static int calcRPN(String[] postfix)
{
    Stack<Integer> st = new Stack<Integer>();
    String value;
    int ans = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < postfix.length; i++){
       value = postfix[i];

       if      (value.equals("+")) ans = st.push(st.pop() + st.pop());
       else if (value.equals("-")) ans = st.push(st.pop() - st.pop());
       else if (value.equals("*")) ans = st.push(st.pop() * st.pop());
       else if (value.equals("/")) ans = st.push(st.pop() / st.pop());
       else st.push(Integer.valueOf(value));
    }

    return ans;
}
```

The output:

```
Postfix: [4, 5, 7, 2, +, -, *], Answer: -16, Your answer: 16 ==> NO match...
Postfix: [3, 4, +, 2, *, 7, /], Answer: 2, Your answer: 0 ==> NO match...
Postfix: [5, 7, +, 6, 2, -, *], Answer: 48, Your answer: -48 ==> NO match...
Postfix: [4, 2, 3, 5, 1, -, +, *, +], Answer: 18, Your answer: 2 ==> NO match...
Postfix: [2, 3, *, 10, 4, /, -], Answer: 4, Your answer: -6 ==> NO match...
Postfix: [4, 23, 12, -, 2, *, +], Answer: 26, Your answer: -18 ==> NO match...
```

The answers should obviously match.  Any ideas?

Comment: What does a debugger tell you?

Answer (score 2):

Hint 1: Some operations (e.g. `/` and `-`) do *not* have the [commutative property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutativity):

> In mathematics, a binary operation is commutative if changing the order of the operands does *not* change the result.

Hint 2: After `push(a); push(b); x = pop(); y = pop`, how do a, b, x, and y relate?

Answer (score 2):

The problem with ur code is that you have reversed the order of operands.
Though this doesnt matter for + and * it *does* matter for / and -.
See this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uh7fD8WiT28

```
Input  Stack(Actual)  Ans(Actual)  Stack(Ur Code)  Ans(ur Code)
  1       1              0            1               0
  2       12             0            12              0
  -       pop()          1-2          pop()x2         2-1=1
```

Another problem with your code is as follows:
Note that using an integer stack does not guarantee the result to be an integer. This may create trouble for you in some cases due to loss of information while doing divisions. Plus You have to push back the answer into the stack so stack needs to be floating point as well.
So you need to use floating point for both the stack and answer.

```
Ex: 2/3 results to 0
((2/3)*3) = > 23/3*
Input Stack
2     2
3     2 3
/     2 3 / =>ans=0
3     0 3
*     0 3 * =>ans=0
/*Wrong Output*/
```

Comment: While the integer division is good to point out, all the input - judging from the failing cases - for this assignment has been specially generated to always be perfectly divisible so no floating point expression are required.

Comment: What on earth do you mean by 'using an integer stack does not a guarantee the result to be an integer'? That is exactly what it *does* guarantee.

Comment: @EJP I meant the actual answer not the answer evaluated by the code.
i.e. 2/3 supposed to be 0.66 would give a 0..